# Making a button that updates an array when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a button that when clicked rolls a die and at the same time counts within the array, yet when I press it the function that I made gives out two different values and the array updates but not with the same answer that the button shows. How do I make both equal the same value? So far this is the code I have:

```
let results = [null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

function rollDie(){
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1)
}

function roll2Die(){
    roll1 = rollDie()
    roll2 = rollDie()
    return roll1 + roll2 
}

let rollBtn = document.getElementById("roll");
let result = document.getElementById("result");
let num = roll2Die();
function dieRoll(num){

    num = roll2Die()
    result.innerHTML = You rolled a ${num}!;
    return num;
}
let graph = document.getElementById("graph")

function newArray(){

    for(let i= 0; i <= results.length; i ++ ) {  
        // results[i].addClass(dieNums);
        if (dieRoll() === i){
            results[i] += 1;   
        }
}
console.table(results)

}

function renderGraph(){

    graph.innerHTML=  You rolled a ${results};

}

rollBtn.addEventListener("click", dieRoll); 

rollBtn.addEventListener("click", renderGraph)

rollBtn.addEve

ntListener("click", newArray)
```

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title>JS and the DOM Assessment</title>

    <!-- CSS-->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Your HTML Here! -->
    <button id="roll">Roll a Pair of Dice</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div id="graph"></div>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add you html code too. what is expected output, can you provide example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `num` parameter from the `dieRoll()` function. Then, In the `newArray` function, you can just push the value of global `num` variable (which gets updated in `dieRoll` function).
Also you need to use backticks (``) for string interpolation. And, Call all the functions once in another function, in the `click` event listener.

```js
let results = []

function rollDie() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1)
}

function roll2Die() {
  roll1 = rollDie()
  roll2 = rollDie()
  return roll1 + roll2
}

let rollBtn = document.getElementById("roll");
let result = document.getElementById("result");
let num = roll2Die();

function dieRoll() {

  num = roll2Die()
  result.innerHTML = `You rolled a ${num}!`;
  return num;
}
let graph = document.getElementById("graph")

function newArray() {
  results.push(num);
}
console.table(results)


function renderGraph() {

  graph.innerHTML = `You rolled a ${results}`;

}

rollBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  dieRoll();
  newArray();
  renderGraph();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <meta name="description" content="Kenzie" />
    <meta name="author" content="Kenzie" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Kenzie" />

    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title>Kenzie JS and the DOM Assessment</title>

    <!-- CSS-->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Your HTML Here! -->
    <button id="roll">Roll a Pair of Dice</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div id="graph"></div>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```